sshd won't start from xinetd in OpenSSH 9.8p1
We start sshd using xinetd on our gateway. Here is the xinetd config file:
service ssh
{
    instances       = 10
    socket_type     = stream
    wait            = no
    user            = root
    protocol        = tcp
    server          = /usr/local/sbin/sshd
    server_args     = -i
    disable         = no
}

Here is OpenSSH version from command ssh -V on the gateway:
OpenSSH_9.8p1, OpenSSL 3.0.14 4 Jun 2024

Here is the version running on my Fedora 37 VM:
OpenSSH_8.8p1, OpenSSL 3.0.9 30 May 2023

If I try to ssh into the gateway from my Fedora 37 VM, I get the "sshd requires execution with an absolute path" error:
$ ssh -vvv foo@g5-5
OpenSSH_8.8p1, OpenSSL 3.0.9 30 May 2023
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug3: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 58: Including file /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/50-redhat.conf depth 0
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/50-redhat.conf
debug2: checking match for 'final all' host g5-5 originally g5-5
debug3: /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/50-redhat.conf line 3: not matched 'final'
debug2: match not found
debug3: /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/50-redhat.conf line 5: Including file /etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/openssh.config depth 1 (parse only)
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/openssh.config
debug3: gss kex names ok: [gss-curve25519-sha256-,gss-nistp256-sha256-,gss-group14-sha256-,gss-group16-sha512-]
debug3: kex names ok: [curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512]
debug1: configuration requests final Match pass
debug1: re-parsing configuration
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug3: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 58: Including file /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/50-redhat.conf depth 0
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/50-redhat.conf
debug2: checking match for 'final all' host g5-5 originally g5-5
debug3: /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/50-redhat.conf line 3: matched 'final'
debug2: match found
debug3: /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/50-redhat.conf line 5: Including file /etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/openssh.config depth 1
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/openssh.config
debug3: gss kex names ok: [gss-curve25519-sha256-,gss-nistp256-sha256-,gss-group14-sha256-,gss-group16-sha512-]
debug3: kex names ok: [curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512]
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts' -> '/home/xxxx/.ssh/known_hosts'
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts2' -> '/home/xxxx/.ssh/known_hosts2'
debug2: resolving "g5-5" port 22
debug3: resolve_host: lookup g5-5:22
debug3: ssh_connect_direct: entering
debug1: Connecting to g5-5 [x.x.x.x] port 22.
debug3: set_sock_tos: set socket 3 IP_TOS 0x48
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/xxxx/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/xxxx/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/xxxx/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/xxxx/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/xxxx/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/xxxx/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/xxxx/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /home/xxxx/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/xxxx/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/xxxx/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/xxxx/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /home/xxxx/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/xxxx/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /home/xxxx/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.8
debug1: kex_exchange_identification: banner line 0: sshd requires execution with an absolute path
kex_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
Connection reset by x.x.x.x port 22

I do not get this error if OpenSSH 9.7p1 is running on the gateway, and I'm able to log in successfully.
I took a look at the code in sshd.c on github: https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable
Is it possible that the error I'm getting is due to not checking the inetd_flag on line 1344? The sshd.c code in 9.7.p1 seems to check for inetd_flag indirectly.
Or is it some new or additional setting with regards to starting 9.8p1 sshd from xinetd?

Since you're investigating the server – what log messages do you get on the server side?

All I'm seeing in /var/log/secure is the xinetd START ssh message

Out of curiosity, why do you start sshd through xinetd?

I encountered the same problem on Slackware (https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/openssh-9-8-regression-when-using-inetd-4175739141/).
It looks like a regression in openssh 9.8 (https://bugzilla.mindrot.org/show_bug.cgi?id=3717) and has been fixed in 9.9 (https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-9.9).
